# Angular Why does accessing nested formgroup through .controls throw error while using [controls] does not

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

When trying to access a nested formgroup like following

```
this.parentForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
  name: [''],
  addressGroup: this.FormBuilder.group({
    street: [''],
    city: ['']
  });
});
```

When try to access street like this.parentForm.controls.addressGroup.controls.street - it throws error Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl', but it does not throw error when accessed like the following this.parentForm.controls.addressGroup['controls'].street

Can someone explain why and what is the reason, I have searched a lot and not able to find any proper reason

Comment: In javascript `object[key]` and `object.key` are supposed to produce the exact same output, so I can't really find any relation to Angular. Maybe it's a typescript issue? While debugging and examining the `parentForm` object, can you find your way to the desired `controls` property? Does it contain the data you expected?

Comment: @fingeron I was able to access parentForm through this.parentForm.controls, I got no problem with that

Answer (score 1):

`FormGroup.controls` return type is `{[key: string]: AbstractControl}`. `this.parentForm.controls.addressGroup` will return `AbstractControl`. This is why you got an error.
As a workaround use `get` method: `this.parentForm.get('addressGroup.street')`.

Comment: I am still confused, I need to know the difference between return type of following FormGroups `this.parentForm` and `this.parentForm.controls.addressGroup`, I think your answer explains - `this.parentForm.controls` and `this.parentForm.controls.addressGroup`, but not what I asked for, anyway thanks :)